# Unable to lock Windows PC by either closing laptop of shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-8.1, lock

I am trying to lock my Dell XPS 15 by using <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> but this doesn't seem to do anything. It used to work and now it doesn't.

I previously experienced this problem and had to recreate my user account. Does anyone know of a solution to this problem that doesn't involve recreating the user profile?

Comment: Can you lock your machine using other methods? Do other key commands work like ctrl alt del?

Comment: What other methods are there? other key commands work just fine. e...g. `Win` + `S` for search.

Comment: Normally from ctrl alt del you can lock Windows from there..

Comment: It's not available from there... hmmm

Comment: That is very odd, so if you create another account (local account rather than Microsoft) and log in do you get 'lock' back?

Comment: I think I will has I previous had to do this for my account, It's just weird that it's happened again :(

Comment: Yeah really strange never seen it before to be honest.. Must be a Windows 8.1 thing... Most likely a bug that microsoft will own up to in about 6 months :)

Comment: So I recreated my account and it happened again! Even tried disabling the sync with microsoft account setting yet it synced my account without even asking!